# Jenkins Mercurial not trusting file

Tags: mercurial, jenkins

I using mercurial and I am trying to point Jenkins toward custom directory. I ran into this error,

```
Started by user Netro
Building in workspace <path-to-workspace>
[workspace] $ hg showconfig paths.default
ERROR: Workspace reports paths.default as Not trusting file <path-to-workspace>/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user root, group root
Not trusting file <path-to-workspace>/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user root, group root
which looks different than http://ip-address/project so falling back to fresh clone rather than incremental update
ERROR: Failed to clean the repository checkout
```

I had searched internet and it suggested add `trusted` field. I had tried with following code in `~/.hgrc, /etc/mercurial/hgrc, <path-to-workspace>/.hg/hgrc`

```
[trusted]
users =  jenkins, root
```

But it doesn't remove error.

When I was ***not*** using custom directory option. It ran successfully.
Installation of Jenkins and repository was done with user root on Ubuntu 1204.
Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, hg was not able to accept jenkins as owner of the projects. Jenkins in default directory creates workspace with user Jenkins. So it is able to run it. I added Jenkins in group root and changed the owner of project from root to jenkins. Now projects are updated from  Jekins.